# Safari hiding elements upon user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, safari

I've never faced this issue ever, so I completely updated my mac + Safari (macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, Safari 14.0.3). The problem is that whatever js interaction I use on my page is bugged in Safari only (work perfectly in FF and Chrome). You can see the kind of animations I use (gradual hiding + showing of elements via max-height + opacity on click of elements) in [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/aLqvmpz9/).

The problem is that Safari behaves very weirdly with these. Sometimes, the clicked element also disappears; disappeared elements fail to reappear when the animation is reset; sometimes one of the not-clicked elements disappears on hover; etc.; really weird things. All this while no console / js error is reported, and things work perfectly smooth in FF and Chrome.

In the Internet I found countless reports about similar behaviour in Safari, but mostly the answer referred to js / css errors. My script's even written in ES5.
I checked about 100 times now, and have none of these errors.

Then I came across [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/280537/some-text-of-website-page-on-iphone-safari-become-invisible), which made me try to change the font. And indeed, everything also works in Safari when I use a default browser font as Arial, etc., but that's obviously not what my client wants.
The font of that site is Bank Gothic Light & Bank Gothic Medium, and I'm using `ttf` and `woff` files as font source files, which I define as custom fonts using `@font-face` in my stylesheets, and then I apply them via `font-family` in my stylesheets. With this, the animations have the mentioned weird behaviour in Safari. Simply when changing the font of the concerned elements to let's say Arial, it all works.

Ideally, I want every animation to work, while sticking to the Gothic fonts in all FF, Chrome AND Safari. Any clue what to do here / why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by getting a new font source file (ttf and woff) from another source; seemed to be buggy (Nothing at all changed in my HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, not in whichever code!). I changed the title of my question to be more general, as one may (at least that was the case for me) totally not think that these Safari - rendering issues are due to the used fonts... To avoid that people with the same issue may not need to search for the reply for hours..